# New line in rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code which i'm using to send a mail.

It is working fine but problem is line breaks and white spaces are automatically getting removed.

E.g.if I type Good then 10 spaces and then Afternoon in richtextbox and send a mail then at receiver side it look like **Good Afternoon** means it keeps only one space But i want send mail as it is how sender typed.

```
var client = new SmtpClient { DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network };

var message = new MailMessage();

message.To.Add(to_textBox.Text);

message.From = new MailAddress(from_textBox.Text);

message.Subject = subject_textBox.Text;

message.IsBodyHtml = true;

string start = "<html><p  style="+'"'+"font-family:'"+fontDialog1.Font.FontFamily.Name+"';"+"font-size:'"+fontDialog1.Font.Size+"'"+'"'+"align="+'"'+message_richTextBox.SelectionAlignment+'"'+">"+message_richTextBox.Text+"</p>"+"</html>";

message.Body = start;

client.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
message_richTextBox.Text
```

To:

```
message_richTextBox.Text.Replace("  ", "&nbsp; ").Replace("\n", "<br>");
```

`&nbsp;` is *non-breaking space*, and `<br>` is *linebreak* in html